# Treeview Child Delphi

Tags: delphi, treeview, delphi-xe6

Good day ...

I have a Treeview, which possess several children:

```
local
----- Son 0
----- Son 1
---------- Recipe 1
-------------------- Value1
----------------------------- Olá1
----------------------------- Olá2
------------------------------------ Select Here
-------------------- Value2
---------- Revenue 2
----- Son 2
----- Son 3
```

Say, I click the son (SELECT HERE), how do I get the first child of the root node (Son 1) ... I have some code that takes the Root, but I would like to take the child of that root that was clicked :

```
p: = Form4.TreeView1.Selected.Parent;
           while Assigned (p.Parent) of the Begin
               p: = p.Parent;
           end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use an additional variable to keep track of "previous node", when you reach the root then the previous one is one you need? Ie

```
Prev := nil;
p := Form4.TreeView1.Selected;
if(p <> nil)then begin
   while Assigned(p.Parent) do begin
      Prev := p;
      p := p.Parent;
   end;
end;
// Prev, if assigned, should be the node you need
```

Comment: This code will crash if `Selected` or `Selected.Parent` is nil.